# Select data from multiple tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, count

I have 6 unique tables with same column `AFFECTED_ITEM`.

I want a query will which output column `AFFECTED_ITEM` and `Count(*)` for each table.

```
SELECT 
     AFFECTED_ITEM, Count(*)
FROM 
    dbo.Table1
WHERE 
    AFFECTED_ITEM IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 
    AFFECTED_ITEM;

SELECT 
    AFFECTED_ITEM, Count(*)
FROM 
    dbo.Table2
WHERE 
    AFFECTED_ITEM IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 
    AFFECTED_ITEM;

...

SELECT 
    AFFECTED_ITEM, Count(*)
FROM 
    dbo.Table6
WHERE 
    AFFECTED_ITEM IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 
    AFFECTED_ITEM;
```

Example:

```
AFFECTED_ITEM | Table1 | Table2 | Table3 | Table6 |
--------------------------------------------------
Item1         |  53    |   45   |   12   |   0    |
Item2         |   4    |   13   |   77   |   9    |
Item3         |   7    |    0   |   24   |   23   |
```

etc..

Comment: ,Provide your sample data of 6 tables and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [Common Table Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) to get a list of all possible values for *AFFECTED_ITEM* from all tables:

```
WITH AffectedItems (AFFECTED_ITEM) AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT AFFECTED_ITEM  FROM table1
  UNION
  SELECT DISTINCT AFFECTED_ITEM  FROM table2
  UNION
  SELECT DISTINCT AFFECTED_ITEM   FROM table3
  UNION
  SELECT DISTINCT AFFECTED_ITEM   FROM table4
  UNION
  SELECT DISTINCT AFFECTED_ITEM   FROM table5
  UNION
  SELECT DISTINCT AFFECTED_ITEM   FROM table6
)
```

Then combine that with the [Group By](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql) clause combine with [LEFT Joins](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518(v=sql.105).aspx) to get the counts:

```
WITH AffectedItems (AFFECTED_ITEM) AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT AFFECTED_ITEM  FROM table1
  UNION
  SELECT DISTINCT AFFECTED_ITEM  FROM table2
  UNION
  SELECT DISTINCT AFFECTED_ITEM   FROM table3
  UNION
  SELECT DISTINCT AFFECTED_ITEM   FROM table4
  UNION
  SELECT DISTINCT AFFECTED_ITEM   FROM table5
  UNION
  SELECT DISTINCT AFFECTED_ITEM   FROM table6
)
SELECT ai.AFFECTED_ITEM, count(t1.name) as table1, count(t2.name) as table2, 
count(t3.name) as table3,count(t4.name) as table4, count(t5.name) as table5, 
count(t6.name) as table6
FROM AffectedItems ai
LEFT JOIN dbo.table1 t1 on t1.AFFECTED_ITEM = ai.AFFECTED_ITEM
LEFT JOIN dbo.table2 t2 on t2.AFFECTED_ITEM = ai.AFFECTED_ITEM
LEFT JOIN dbo.table3 t3 on t3.AFFECTED_ITEM = ai.AFFECTED_ITEM
LEFT JOIN dbo.table1 t4 on t4.AFFECTED_ITEM = ai.AFFECTED_ITEM
LEFT JOIN dbo.table2 t5 on t5.AFFECTED_ITEM = ai.AFFECTED_ITEM
LEFT JOIN dbo.table3 t6 on t6.AFFECTED_ITEM = ai.AFFECTED_ITEM
GROUP BY ai.AFFECTED_ITEM
```

See it demonstrated in this [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6f594/1/0).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `LEFT JOIN` and `Count Distinct` in key columns

```
SELECT t.AFFECTED_ITEM, 
    Count(DISTINCT t1.KeyId ) AS Table1,
    Count(DISTINCT t2.KeyId ) AS Table2,
    Count(DISTINCT t3.KeyId ) AS Table3,
    Count(DISTINCT t4.KeyId ) AS Table4,
    Count(DISTINCT t5.KeyId ) AS Table5,
    Count(DISTINCT t6.KeyId ) AS Table6

FROM yourTable t
LEFT JOIN Table1 t1 ON t.AFFECTED_ITEM = t1.AFFECTED_ITEM
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t.AFFECTED_ITEM = t2.AFFECTED_ITEM
LEFT JOIN Table3 t3 ON t.AFFECTED_ITEM = t3.AFFECTED_ITEM
LEFT JOIN Table4 t4 ON t.AFFECTED_ITEM = t4.AFFECTED_ITEM
LEFT JOIN Table5 t5 ON t.AFFECTED_ITEM = t5.AFFECTED_ITEM
LEFT JOIN Table6 t6 ON t.AFFECTED_ITEM = t6.AFFECTED_ITEM

GROUP BY t.AFFECTED_ITEM
```

Comment: I have an error Ambiguous column name 'AFFECTED_ITEM'

Answer (score 0):

Left join is not true reault you need full outer join 2 by 2  like this :

```
with CteT1AndT2 as (
 SELECT  coalesce(t1.AFFECTED_ITEM,t2.AFFECTED_ITEM) as AFFECTED_ITEM, 
    Count(DISTINCT t1.KeyId ) AS CntTable1,
    Count(DISTINCT t2.KeyId ) AS CntTable2,

   FROM  Table1 t1 
     FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 ON t1.AFFECTED_ITEM = t2.AFFECTED_ITEM
    GROUP BY t1.AFFECTED_ITEM,t2.AFFECTED_ITEM
)
```

Then repeat it for next 2 tables and next two ones then full join all the results with each other. It will be a long query but you won't loose ant data for sure.

Take a look at this link : http://www.dofactory.com/sql/full-outer-join you need full join then for avoiding null values need 'coalesce', LEFT JOIN is absolutely wrong and you will loose data in right table.

Answer (score 0):

First insert all your table1 , table2 ... table6 data to temp table.After that use PIVOT concept based on that temp table

```
  CREATE TABLE #table(AFFECTED_ITEM VARCHAR(100),_Count INT,_table 
  VARCHAR(100))

  INSERT INTO #table(AFFECTED_ITEM ,_Count , _table )
  SELECT AFFECTED_ITEM, Count(*),'Table1'
  FROM dbo.Table1
  WHERE AFFECTED_ITEM IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY AFFECTED_ITEM 

  INSERT INTO #table(AFFECTED_ITEM ,_Count , _table )
  SELECT AFFECTED_ITEM, Count(*),'Table2'
  FROM dbo.Table2
  WHERE AFFECTED_ITEM IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY AFFECTED_ITEM 

  .......  Upto table6 


  SELECT AFFECTED_ITEM , ISNULL([Table1],0) [Table1] , ISNULL([Table2],0) 
  [Table2] , ISNULL([Table3],0) [Table3] , ISNULL([Table4],0) [Table4] , 
  ISNULL([Table5],0) [Table5],ISNULL([Table6],0) [Table6]
  FROM 
  (
     SELECT AFFECTED_ITEM , _Count , _table     
     FROM #table
  ) A
  PIVOT
 (
   SUM(_Count) FOR _table IN ([Table1],[Table2],[Table3],[Table4],[Table5],
   [Table6])
 ) pvt
```

Comment: @Keilash,I posted answer for your question.Try above query.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following...

```
SELECT itemCountFinder1.AFFECTED_ITEM AS AFFECTED_ITEM,
       COALESCE( itemCount1, 0 ) AS Table1,
       COALESCE( itemCount2, 0 ) AS Table2,
       COALESCE( itemCount3, 0 ) AS Table3,
       COALESCE( itemCount4, 0 ) AS Table4,
       COALESCE( itemCount5, 0 ) AS Table5,
       COALESCE( itemCount6, 0 ) AS Table6
FROM ( SELECT AFFECTED_ITEM,
              Count( * ) AS itemCount1
       FROM dbo.Table1
       WHERE AFFECTED_ITEM IS NOT NULL
       GROUP BY AFFECTED_ITEM ) AS itemCountFinder1
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT AFFECTED_ITEM,
                   Count( * ) AS  AS itemCount2
            FROM dbo.Table2
            WHERE AFFECTED_ITEM IS NOT NULL
            GROUP BY AFFECTED_ITEM ) AS itemCountFinder2 ON itemCountFinder1.AFFECTED_ITEM = itemCountFinder2.AFFECTED_ITEM
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT AFFECTED_ITEM,
                   Count( * ) AS itemCount3
            FROM dbo.Table3
            WHERE AFFECTED_ITEM IS NOT NULL
            GROUP BY AFFECTED_ITEM ) AS itemCountFinder3 ON itemCountFinder1.AFFECTED_ITEM = itemCountFinder3.AFFECTED_ITEM
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT AFFECTED_ITEM,
                   Count( * ) AS itemCount4
            FROM dbo.Table4
            WHERE AFFECTED_ITEM IS NOT NULL
            GROUP BY AFFECTED_ITEM ) AS itemCountFinder4 ON itemCountFinder1.AFFECTED_ITEM = itemCountFinder4.AFFECTED_ITEM
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT AFFECTED_ITEM,
                   Count( * ) AS itemCount5
            FROM dbo.Table5
            WHERE AFFECTED_ITEM IS NOT NULL
            GROUP BY AFFECTED_ITEM ) AS itemCountFinder5 ON itemCountFinder1.AFFECTED_ITEM = itemCountFinder5.AFFECTED_ITEM
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT AFFECTED_ITEM,
                   Count( * ) AS itemCount6
            FROM dbo.Table6
            WHERE AFFECTED_ITEM IS NOT NULL
            GROUP BY AFFECTED_ITEM ) AS itemCountFinder6 ON itemCountFinder1.AFFECTED_ITEM = itemCountFinder6.AFFECTED_ITEM
```

Here we left join five of the datasets returned by your six queries to the sixth query on the common value `AFFECTED_ITEM` (the order in which you do so does not matter in this case).

We then `SELECT` each row from the newly formed dataset and display each of the count fields.  Coalesce is used to display a `0` where no count exists for that value of `AFFECTED_ITEM`.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.